# AES: Given two deterministic plaintexts, compute two keys let the ciphertext is the same, is it possible?

Tags: aes

Given two plaintexts $p_1$ and $p_2$, is it possible to find two keys for AES(-CBC) so that $$E_{k_1}(p_1) = E_{k_2}(p_2) $$

I want to make sure that will never happen, or is there any way to prevent that from happening? Because that will make my system unreliable.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good, it means deterministic input.

Comment: For example, here are two texts, one is "aaa" and one is "bbb", is it possible to compute two keys let the ciphertext of "aaa" is the same as the ciphertext of "bbb"?

Comment: I've edited our question, make sure that it is what you want. Secondly, could you elaborate on your real problem? What mode of operation you have to use, ECB, CBC, CTR. etc...

Comment: Thanks!! This is what I mean. I use the CBC mode. My purpose is to make sure that this is impossible, so that I can make sure that the system I am designing is reliable, otherwise I might consider designing another solution.

Comment: My problem is to prove that different plaintexts can't quickly find two keys in a short time let their ciphertexts are the same.

Comment: For typical ciphers, for every ciphertext you can apply multiple unique keys to decrypt it into multiple plaintexts. Usually only the original key will lead to a meaningful plaintext decryption - but keep in mind that even random looking plaintexts are valid plaintexts! This is true for all encryption algorithms based around permutations or stream ciphers or similar constructions. However, if you start with two arbitary plaintexts, it's much more difficult for most ciphers (OTP excluded) to find keys resulting in identical ciphertexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What is the mathematical property stating that it is hard to find a collision in the AES algorithm?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/61102/what-is-the-mathematical-property-stating-that-it-is-hard-to-find-a-collision-in/61123#61123)

The answer of Lindell is important.

For an adversary with infinite computation power it is always possible to find $p_1$ and $p_2$ s.t. $E_{k_1}(p_1) = E_{k_2}(p_2)$. Choose any values $k_1, k_2$ with $k_1 \neq k_2$ and calculate $p_3 = E^{-1}_{k_2}(E_{k_1}(p_1))$ and stop if $p_3 = p_2$, otherwise repeat with different $k_2$.

However if the question is how easy it is to find such $k_1, k_2$ it is a different story.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is what I want.

Comment: Is it really "always possible", or just possible with an extremely high likelihood?

Comment: It is always possible (for an adversary with infinite computation power) since AES is a bijection and $E_{k_1},E_{k_2}$ share the same input/output space.